# Killing Windows 10 update from another PC

Tags: windows-10, boot, windows-update, reboot

**The problem:**

My PC (Windows 10) is stuck in Update reboot loop. It would take hours to get to the login screen and then it reboots again.

**What I already tried:**

- Accessing Command Promt from a bootable USB disk (which didn't boot).
- Launching Windows 10 in Safe Mode (which did start and take me to a custom CMD window and offered formating a disk partition)
- Different boot options and BIOS configurations.

**Where I'm at:**

I took the HDD out and connected to another (Windows XP 32bit) PC via HDD docking station (USB). A disk check (done from CMD) was necessary for the System partition to be accessible.

**What I'm trying to do:**

Stop the Windows update, reboot loop and prepare a clean boot of the Windows 10 by configuring the right files in the System partition. In another words - fix Win10 while it is not running from another WinXP PC.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Check out this answer with similar solutions in Window 7 that should help you regardless with the Windows 10 issue: http://superuser.com/questions/993233/failed-to-configure-restart-loop-with-windows-7-updates/993243#993243