# How do I enable system protection from the command prompt in the system repair screen?

Tags: windows-7, command-line, system-restore

I had disabled system protection trying to download DirectX 10, because my graphics can't support DirectX 11. Some Windows updates started after I turned off my computer,  I figured it wouldn't be a problem until my computer started back up again and gave me the "failure configuring  windows updates" error, and is in a continuous loop.

It happened before, but I had restored it to a previous session. I can't do that again because system protection is off and it is saying it doesn't have restore points, though I do believe it does.

Windows 7 ultimate

Comment: See the post here for the specific steps to take to try to resolve this issue: https://superuser.com/questions/993233/failed-to-configure-restart-loop-with-windows-7-updates/993243#993243

Answer (score 0):

> I can't do that again because system protection is off and it is saying it doesn't have restore points, though I do believe it does.

**Fact:** When you disable your System Protection, all System Restore checkpoints are deleted. For years, I disabled and immediately re-enabled System Protection when I wanted to delete all System Restore checkpoints.

> How do I enable system protection from the command prompt in the system repair screen?

While I don't know whether it is possible to do it from Command Prompt at all, I know that it is impossible to enable System Protection when the operating system is offline.

Answer (score -2):

Try this: `rstrui.exe /offline:C:\Windows=active`

Comment: This answer could be improved by providing more explanation of what exactly this command does.