# Windows 10 stuck in BSOD reboot loop

Tags: windows-10, bsod

I recently suffered a power brief power outage which casued my Windows 10 PC to reboot.

When it began its reboot cycle, I got a "BSOD" with a notice saying:

```
 Page fault in non-paged area
```

It then began rebooting itself and then this appeared:

```
 KMODE Exception not handled
```

And then it began rebooting again where it eventually came up with:

```
 Driver IRQL not less or equal
```

It just continually reboots into "Automatic startup repair" before showing these faults and rebooting again - stuck in this endless cycle.

To make matters worse, my BIOS is configured to not boot from USB drives so although I could make a Windows 10 recovery USB drive from another PC, I would be able to boot from it. Even worse, my BIOS is configured to fastboot so I can't even get into my BIOS to change these boot settings! No amount of pressing DEL or F2 can get me into the BIOS config utility

What can I do to interrupt this BSOD loop and resume normal operations?

For info: I have a Gigabyte Z170X Gaming 7 motherboard, and a wireless logitech keyboard - I don't have access to a wired KB
The OS is booting from an Intel 600p M.2 PCIe SSD drive.  I have 2x GTX-1080 cards but not sure that's relevant unless something has gone wrong with the nVidia drivers.

Comment: I've got fastboot enabled too, but I can access BIOS by pressing F2 button before pressing the power button. Try shutting down the PC by holding power button, then perform the aforementioned actions.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a try - just to confirm, that's keeping the F2 button held down at power off and leave it held down when the power button is pressed (until it boots into BIOS?)

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: Boot pressing either `F8` or `F8`+ `Shift` at boot and see if that gets you to the "Recovery console". From there in command prompt run `chkdsk /f /r` and press enter. Reboot and see if it's still looping. If so, boot into it again and from command prompt run `sfc /scannow` and press enter. Let that run and see if that resolves. Otherwise, look over my answer here for things try: https://superuser.com/questions/993233/failed-to-configure-restart-loop-with-windows-7-updates/993243#993243 .... Yes, with **Windows 10**, yes with **Windows 10** too, and yes with **Windows 10** as well.

Comment: Can't get into the recovery console using either F8 or shift+F8.  I'm booting from a USB recovery drive but don't have any of the advanced options, so I can't get into safe mode.  I'm totally stuck!  I've run chkdsk and sfc from the command console and no errors were reported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your boot hard disk is damaged.

Disconnecting the boot disk will surely get you into the BIOS so you can
reset your boot options.

Use a Windows 10 installation/recovery media for repairing Windows startup.
See for that the article
[Boot to Advanced Startup Options in Windows 10](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2294-boot-advanced-startup-options-windows-10-a.html).
In the worst case, you will need to reinstall Windows.

Use first a Linux live CD to save your data.

Comment: I ended up re-installing the OS.  Not fun but at least I've got my PC working again!  Really puzzled why I couldn't get to the Advanced Startup option while the disk was in this "corrupt" state.  Even more bizzarely, once the SSD had been formatted and re-partitioned and re-installed windows, I inadvertantly booted from the USB flash drive and the advanced startup options were displayed!

Answer (score 0):

only try this answer IF you have,

1. Any live os disk (dvd or cd).(linux ,windows any)
2. A working optical drive . i.e Dvd drive.

and  if your BIOS is configured to boot from dvd drive FIRST,then just put dvd of live os into it and reboot pc and repair SSD.

or remove SSD and boot your pc to see if it goes into bios?

or Reset cmos (take out small battery and reinsert it) and see if you can get into bios ?

if no then 
check  your keyboard on another pc or atleast be sure that your keyboard is working..

if you are using wireless keyboad via usb dongles then try to plug that dongle on different usb ports.

if still no luck then last option 
buy PS2 or USB keyboard (prefer PS2 over USB) as per your motherboard's spec.
because keyboard is cheapest hardware nowadays

done...

Comment: I haven't owned an optical drive (or media) for about 10 years!  You should be able to substiute the words DVD/CD for USB boot drive