# crash/reboot loop after changing from uefi to csm boot

Tags: windows-8, boot, bios, crash, infinite-loop

I wanted to change the boot order to USB first on a Windows8 Samsung (NP300E5C) laptop to install LinuxMint, but there was only "1. Windows Boot Manager", no USB or CD option.
So I started fiddling with the settings, and disabled Secureboot and changed the boot mode from "UEFI only" to "CSM only" to see if there was a change. Rebooted, and pressed F2 to enter Boot settings, but the laptop crashed and rebooted, crashed again after one second and reboots again, crashes, reboots seemingly infinitely.

Edit2&3: I disassembled the whole mainboard and exchanged the CMOS battery with a 10 Eurocent coin for two days. Now the BIOS settings are restored to default, and I can start again (but only with the HDD plugged, else I have that crash reboot loop).
Now I'm at square one, because there is only 1 device in the boot order and it is "1. Windows Boot Manager". I want to make the laptop start booting with CD/DVD drive, then USB, then Windows. Any ideas?

Comment: See if anything suggested here helps: https://superuser.com/questions/993233/failed-to-configure-restart-loop-with-windows-7-updates/993243#993243 simple enough just in case and applicable

Comment: Doesn't help sadly, because I don't get as far as the console. I crash after 1 second in.

Comment: have you tried removing tried removing your HDD and connecting it to a different computer to see if you can have access to your files? or Insert a different HDD in your HDD port to see if your computer reads it?

Comment: No need, because the problem is not the HDD, because the problem persists when I unplug it.