# Windows update stuck in "Your device is at risk" loop

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-update

I've just installed Windows 10 Pro 1709 on a new workstation, so I went directly to "Windows update" without doing **anything** else before. It updated a few things, but now it keeps saying that

> Your device is at risk because it’s out of date and missing important
>   security and quality updates.

When I press `Check for updates` it runs the check for a bit and then comes back repeating the above message, over and over.

I've tried running the "Windows update troubleshooter" but to no avail.
I've tried installing a cumulative patch (KB4074588) but still no luck.

What could I try next?

Comment: Have you rebooted the machine? Sometimes it has installed updates and requires a restart to finish those installs before it can continue to install updates. This process sometimes takes place in the background and is invisible to the user.

Comment: Restart, Clear the update cache, restart again, and try again.

Comment: @LPChip: yes rebooted lots of times :)

Comment: @DigitalLightcraft: do you mean, delete the SoftwareDistribution directory? Still "your device is at risk" :(

Comment: KB4074595 is a Adobe Flash update.  Why are you installing it to fix this problem?  It also was released a month ago.

Comment: @Ramhound: Sorry, copied the wrong KB number! I'll fix the question

Comment: Joril - [I uninstalled this update (KB4058043) and did a manual cumulative update (KB4073290) which fixed the issue for me. Since then the error is gone from the Windows update.](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-update-winpc/error-message-your-device-is-at-risk-because-its/39c78a25-e9b8-48da-80db-803ab7be7fea?page=2).... give that a shot and perhaps it'll resolve. Otherwise look over some of the detail on https://superuser.com/questions/993233/failed-to-configure-restart-loop-with-windows-7-updates/993243#993243 potentially.

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT: I have no KB4058043 installed, anyway I tried the remove+cumulative way but again no luck

Comment: That same post suggested someone manually downloaded and installed [KB4056892](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4056892/windows-10-update-kb4056892) from a comment so see if that's installed or not already.

Comment: After trying all the suggested solutions I gave up and reinstalled from scratch, went straight to "Windows update" and after a few reboots/rechecks it is finally saying that it's up to date. Many thanks to everyone all the same!