# Windows 10 recovery/restore infinite loop without login access

Tags: windows, boot, restore, asus-laptop, infinite-loop

my asus laptop TP300L is stuck in an infinite loop, I cannot access windows as the computer reboots before I can do anything.

**Situation**

here is the sequence of screens I get:

1. asus logo
2. a spinner appears
3. for less than a second the shape of a windows terminal appears, but without any content, no button, no text, just the shape of window
4. the text "tentative de récupération de l'installation" (attempt to recover the installation) appears
5. the text "restoration de votre version antéireur de windows" (restore your previous version of windows) replaces the text of step3
6. blank screen and reboots (no windows login or whatever) immediately, back to screen 1

**Failed attempts:**

I have tried pressing F2 F8 F9 F10 and F11 at step 1, this does not respond.

I can press escape at step 1, which allows be to choose between the "setup" and the windows boot manager:

- The setup option brings me strait to the bios, this bios doesn't not have any restore options anywhere. Only hardware/date options.
- The windows boot manager option bring's to the sequence of screens I described earlier

I have tried hard-reboot the laptop during step 1 three times in a row as recommended on asus troubleshooting section. This is supposed sending the user to a recovery/failproof mode but doesnt work.

Note : This issue happens after another annoying but not blocking issue that latest for weeks :  Windows 10 was performing a background update and request the user to reboot even update was complete. The system booted, trying installing, failed, restored previous version and trying updating again.
Microsoft support wasn't able to fix the issue, after 2 calls and even with a remote connexion session with a support tech (because he had to reboot the machine and the technician had to leave for lunch break...). I gave up on uselessly calling Microsoft.

Note 2: this is not an upgrade from windows 7 or 8. The machine was delivered with windows 10, 2 years ago.

**edit 2018-04-16** Using an install usb stick, I can boot to usb and in the menu "start a different operating system" I have two options : the first is just a icon, no text describing the system, the second is windows 10 and it can boot fine to windows from there. I suspect some kind of partition created by the update to be selected instead of the normal windows. How can I fix this ?

**Goal**

My goal is to reach some kind of recovery partition and restore from factory delivered version, does someone have a clue ?

Comment: Just asking. Have you also tried F9 or Fn+F9 continuously (keep repeating)? Does not it respond at all? And also, what is the model number of your laptop?

Comment: the model is a tp300l , I have just tried pressing down F9 and fn+F9  through the whole sequence without results. I did notice that my mouse cursor was briefly appears during the step where the windows terminal  appears if I move the mouse

Comment: I want you to try this out if possible.
- Shutdown the laptop.
- Unplug.
- Remove the battery.
- Press and hold the power button for like 20-30 seconds.
- Once this is complete, try installing the battery and then power plugs.
Then try starting and this time, try using F9 first.
If you already have any Windows bootable drivers (DVD/USB) we can perform a reset from the recovery options. Sometimes in Asus F9 stops working due to various issues inc. BIOS settings, Windows upgrades, and driver related issues. I hope the memory modules are in good health as well.

Comment: In case you find any of these steps helpful: https://superuser.com/questions/993233/failed-to-configure-restart-loop-with-windows-7-updates/993243#993243

Comment: For the record, I formatted and reinstalled windows....